# quicker way in microsoft excel

Tags: excel-2010

Ultimately, I need to figure out the quickest way to get the total for the de-duplicated donors on this donation list.  I know how to do this by using `AutoSum`. For example I could get the total for Orthopaedics by typing `=SUM(C1, C2, C3, C4)` That would equal 1500.

Here is an example of what is going to be on the excel table.

```
DATE              NAME          Value
10/10/2012  , Orthopaedics      500
10/20/2011  , Orthopaedics      250
10/10/2012  , Orthopaedics      500
10/20/2011  , Orthopaedics      250
8/12/2011   , John              500
8/12/2011   , John              500
10/10/2011  , John              100
1/2/2013    , Andres            500
8/10/2011   , Andres            1000
12/26/2013  John Smith          500
10/2/2012   Alex Taster         1000
10/26/2011  Jared Comes         250
10/27/2011  Shawn Derek         2000
```

I wonder if I could create a `tab/line` that I could copy and paste it to get the total for each group.

The difficult part is that the number of donations for each donor varies.

It might be something like: `=If(NAME = B1) SUM(C1 + C?)`  the question mark for that line.

I am looking for a quicker way to get the total for each donor, who might have one or multiple donations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a simple `Sumif` will do:

```
=SUMIF($B:$B,$B2,$C:$C)
```

This will give the total for each Donator.